# CouchDB emit on OR match

Tags: couchdb

I have query related with CouchDB:

Let's consider my *DB name*: **test**, *view name*: **user-view** & *design name*: **_design/user**.

I have following *documents* in *couchdb*:

```
{ "name" :"ABC", "city" :"Mumbai" }
{ "name" :"PQR", "city" :"Mumbai" }
{ "name" :"XYZ", "city" :"Pune" }
{ "name" :"ABC", "city" :"Pune" }
```

I have following **user-view**:

```
function(doc) {
   emit([doc.name, doc.city], doc);
}
```

When I send following *GET request*:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5984/test/_design/user/_view/user-view?include_docs=true&key=['ABC','Pune']
```

I get following result:

```
{ "name" :"ABC", "city" :"Pune" }
```

Suppose I have only values for either **name** or **city** at a time and I want to use same *view* **user-view** and get following results:

**Case 1** Only *name* is available as **ABC**

I should get following result:

```
[
  { "name" :"ABC", "city" :"Mumbai" }
  { "name" :"ABC", "city" :"Pune" }
]
```

**Case 2** Only *city* is available as **Pune**

I should get following result:

```
[
   { "name" :"XYZ", "city" :"Pune" }
   { "name" :"ABC", "city" :"Pune" }
]
```

**Case 3** Only *name* as **ABC** and *city* as **Pune** is available

I should get following result:

```
[
   { "name" :"ABC", "city" :"Mumbai" }
   { "name" :"XYZ", "city" :"Pune" }
   { "name" :"ABC", "city" :"Pune" }
]
```

Now consider I have multiple *keys* (**name, city, region, zip-code,** etc.) and at a time it is possible that I could have any single or multiple combinations of *keys* to query (e.g. only value for *name* available at a time or only value for *city* and *region* available at a time and etc) and I don't want to end up in creating multiple views. Is it possible to use single view and still able to get *results* for any combination of *keys*?

Answer (score -1):

This is technically possible, but ill-advised.

The way to use the same view for cities and names is to emit both in your map function:

```js
function(doc) {
   emit(doc.name, doc);
   emit(doc.city, doc);
}
```

The *reason* this is ill-advised is that you'll never know if what you're querying is a city or a name. And if you have a person named the same as a city, for example, you'll get both results.

So the correct way to handle this is with two views, one for cities, and one for names.

You could work around this by qualifying the key type in your map function, but this complicates your queries, too, because you must specify which key type you want to query:

```js
function(doc) {
   emit("name:"+doc.name, doc);
   emit("city:"+doc.city, doc);
}
```

It will be somewhat more efficient in terms of disk usage, index query speed (although probably marginally so), and readability of your queries, to use two views.

Comment: The reason i was insisting to use same **view** is that suppose I have multiple _keys (name, city, region, zip-code, etc._ and it's possible i get any single or multiple combinations of _keys_ at each time to query, so this might result in creating multiple **views**.

Comment: If your goal is to find all matches of a key, regardless of which field they go in, then a single view makes sense. But that also sounds a bit more like a full text search, and would probably be best accomplished with CouchDB 3.1's [full text search](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/master/ddocs/search.html) feature.

Comment: I have rephrased the question could you please go through it once?